# AES javafx program showing error during a press of encryption button

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

impemented AES algorithm using javafx "well am trying to implement" but it gives me no error when i compile the code but it does when i pressed an encryption button it show a bunch of error in the command line

the code are as follows

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESGui extends Application{

    TextArea inputArea = new TextArea();
    TextArea outputArea = new TextArea();
    Main object1 = new Main();

    public static void main(String [] args){
        launch (args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){

        HBox hbox1 = new HBox(50);
        hbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox1.getChildren().addAll(inputArea, outputArea);

        Button encrypt = new Button("Encrypt");
        encrypt.setOnAction (event -> {
            object1.aesEncryption();
        });

        Button decrypt = new Button("Decrypt");

        HBox hbox2 = new HBox(50);
        hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox2.getChildren().addAll(encrypt, decrypt);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox1, hbox2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 900, 700);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("aes gui");
        stage.show();
    }

    public class AESAlgorithm{
        public String algo = "AES";
        public byte[] keyValue;

        public AESAlgorithm(String key){
            keyValue = key.getBytes();
        }

        public Key generateKey() throws Exception{
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, algo);
            return key;
        }

        public String encrypt(String msg) throws Exception{

            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(msg.getBytes());
            String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
            return encryptedValue;

        }

        public String decrypt(String msg) throws Exception{

            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(msg);
            byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
            String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
            return decryptedValue;
        }
    }

    public class Main {
        AESAlgorithm aesAlgo;
        private byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{'t','h','e','b','e','s','t','s','e','c','r','e','t','k','e','y'};
        public Main(){
            //initComponents();
            //here we passed key to constructor
            aesAlgo = new AESAlgorithm("MySecretKey");
        }

        private void aesEncryption(){
            try{

                String plainText = inputArea.getText();
                String encryptedText = aesAlgo.encrypt(plainText);
                outputArea.setText(encryptedText);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the output from the cmd when i press the encryption button is

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 11 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(AESCipher.java:509)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1067)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1025)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
at AESGui$AESAlgorithm.encrypt(AESGui.java:79)
at AESGui$Main.aesEncryption(AESGui.java:111)
at AESGui$Main.access$000(AESGui.java:98)
at AESGui.lambda$start$0(AESGui.java:42)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is too short. AES works with 128bit, 192bit and 256bit keys.

You have defined `keyValue`, which is a 16 byte array (16*8 = 128bit). Use that instead.

```
public class Main {
        AESAlgorithm aesAlgo;
        private byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{'t','h','e','b','e','s','t','s','e','c','r','e','t','k','e','y'};
        public Main(){
            //initComponents();
            //here we passed key to constructor
            aesAlgo = new AESAlgorithm(keyValue);
        }

        private void aesEncryption(){
            try{

                String plainText = inputArea.getText();
                String encryptedText = aesAlgo.encrypt(plainText);
                outputArea.setText(encryptedText);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: how do i specify a 128bit key can you give me an example?

Comment: You can use every string made of 16 characters (ASCII) in order to get a 128 bit key, for example.

Comment: @llario Pierbattista is the one am using in the code if you can trace the **key value** in my code is the one am using but yet it still shows the short key error `public class AESAlgorithm{
  public String algo = "AES";
  public byte[] keyValue;

  public AESAlgorithm(String key){
   keyValue = key.getBytes();
  }

  public Key generateKey() throws Exception{
   Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, algo);
   return key;
  }`

Comment: thanks @Ilario  it worked i was not passing same key to class above.